# Implications of "For official use only"

Tags: usa, government, releasing-data, uses-of-open-data

Certain US government websites ([fpds.gov](https://www.fpds.gov/fpdsng_cms/index.php/en/), [sam.gov](https://www.sam.gov/portal/SAM/##11), among others) have a footer saying something along the lines

> This is a U.S. General Services Administration Federal Government
>   computer system that is "FOR OFFICIAL USE ONLY." This system is
>   subject to monitoring. Individuals found performing unauthorized
>   activities are subject to disciplinary action including criminal
>   prosecution.

Wikipedia [mentions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_Official_Use_Only) this term, but it refers to unpublished documents.

These websites are freely available (no IP, login restrictions) and often contain the same data as government websites without this note, like [fbo.gov](http://www.fbo.gov/).

What are the implications of this note in the context of such public websites? What license agreements apply in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning says nothing about using the data. Unauthorized *activities* are prohibited. Don't set up your own website or store your vacation images on their servers even if there is unfettered access or because your *special set of skills*  make it easy to gain unfettered access. Storing your images is not an ***official*** use.

Inside the US gov't we have similar warnings about accessing systems. Although US federal law prohibits unauthorized access and activities the warning you see on-screen is one more *in your face* warning that helps to defeat the "I didn't know I couldn't do that" defense.